# static website hosting in s3 using aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static, aws-sdk

I am trying to perform static website hosting on s3 that has a simple image file, using aws-sdk from my local ide.
The code runs without any error and it reflects on my console as well but when i open the endpoint from console it doesn't open the file.
The file is in the bucket as well and i have enabled public access. But if i am doing the same through console i mean enabling static website hosting it opens.
This is the code...

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const fs = require('fs');

const filecon = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Users\\Envy\\Desktop\\murugan.jpeg');

(async function(){

try {
    aws.config.setPromisesDependency();
    aws.config.update({
        region: 'us-east-1'
    })
    const a1 = await s3.createBucket({Bucket:'ommuruga'}).promise();
    const a2 = await s3.upload({Bucket:'ommuruga',Key:'murugan.jpeg',Body:filecon,ACL:'public-read'}).promise();
    const a3 = await s3.putBucketWebsite({Bucket:'ommuruga',WebsiteConfiguration:{IndexDocument:{Suffix:'murugan.jpeg'},ErrorDocument:{Key:'Error.html'}}}).promise();
    console.log(a3);
}       
catch(err){
    console.log(`unable to process err: ${err}`);
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **setup permissions** for the s3 website to work as explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html):

- disable S3 Block Public Access
- add readonly bucket policy